# MS Access 2016 VBA - modify TextBox via VBA in Tabular Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

the problem I have seems to be related with the tabular form which allows showing multiple entries at the same time.

I want to have one column (A) calculated from another column (B) but (A) shall still be editable. If I use ControlSource for (A) the underlying textbox becomes non-editable. The same applies for the usage of queries. Both options are not good. Therefore I want to use VBA code that modifies the content of (A) based on changes in (B). And vice versa, if the user modifies (A), (B) gets updated. Btw. (A) does not get stored in the database, only (B).

Problem is, if I update the value of (A) via VBA during an event of (B), the whole column (A) shows the same value and is not calculated line by line in the tabular form mode. Any assistance / help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An unbound textbox will show the same value for all records. Period.

2-way data dependency is unusual. Think I have seen something like it only once. Involved calculating square footage. User entered rectangular dimensions then had choice of entering the actual footage to account for irregular boundaries or cutouts and the adjustment was calculated or entering the adjustment and the actual was calculated. User had to select a radio button to designate the editable control. This was not on a continuous records form, just single record.

Comment: Good example. To be more specific, it is not a real two way data dependency I want to create here. Let's say Column B is the value I store in the database, it is always in feet. The user cannot enter in B only in A. Next to Column A and B I provide Column C which stores the preferred unit in the database - either feet or meters. Now in the first render of all columns I want VBA to calculate from B to A using the conversion factor of C. That is the only moment the data goes the way from B to A. From then on the user can overwrite A and the value gets converted to B. Tabular Form.

Comment: If I store A in the database, it works but is against normalization. If I use ControlSource it works for the first part (from B to A) but then the user cannot enter - can he? If I use it in a single record from it work, but not in a tabular form. I need a record individual editable entry text box in a tabular form which value is not directly stored in the database, only it's derivative.

Comment: It is a balancing act between normalization and getting the job done. If this is behavior you really want then possibly have to 'bend the rules'. I suspect a bound textbox saving the A value is the only way you will get this to work in datasheet/continuous form.